# Is there any way to return comma separated string containing the values of the properties of a C# object.?

Tags: c#, reflection, tostring, stringbuilder

Looking for Solution to return property names on header and then values

```
public override string ToString()
    {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        var props = this.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance); //        string typeName = this.GetType().Name;


        var itemStr = string.Join(", ",
       props.Select(p => p.GetValue(this,null)? .ToString())
          .ToArray());
        return itemStr.ToString();

    }
}
```

I try to use string. Join but its returning only values like john, smith.But I need in following format.
"firstname","lastname" and then in next line its values
"John","smith"
"Mary","land"

Comment: The name of the property is a property of the PropertInfo representing each property. When a property value is `null`, you probably want to include it somehow,  perhaps as `[null]` rather than `"SomeString"`. If you want two lines of text the way you describe, you're going to want to loop through the PropertyInfos twice, once for the name and another time for the values, constructing the two lines you describe